# Upgrade django in a dokku environment

Tags: django, pip, dokku

I need to upgrade the version of django that is running in a dokku container.

I tried

```
dokku run staging pip install Django==1.8.18 --upgrade
```

But when I checked the django version it was still `1.8.13`

I've also tried `dokku ps:rebuild staging`, also with no result.

How am I meant to do the upgrade?

Comment: did you try upgrading [dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku~v0.10.5/getting-started/upgrading/)?

Answer (score 1):

You should update your `requirements.txt` and re-push your application. Containers created via the `dokku run` command are one-off, ephemeral containers.